# jsp only updated after delete browser history

Tags: jsp, refresh

My JSP page isn't updated after change when viewed in web browser. I can only view the latest update after cleared my browser history.(chrome Version 35.0.1916.114 and firefox version 29.0.1)

This is what I have tried without success.
1. restart my local tomcat server after change my jsp file, that didn't work. 
2. added below to my jsp file, also no effect.

```
<% response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1 
 response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0 
 response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server  
%>
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

At moment, the only method works is to clear browser history and hit refresh button.

I tried to debug my project, it seems the corresponding struts2 actions are getting executed  correctly, but the result jsp file is not getting executed until the browser history is cleared.

Can anyone provide me any pointer?

Thanks

Comment: Try with `Expires=-1`

Comment: @Braj I just tried set response.setDateHeader ("Expires", -1); and <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />, it doesn't work. I understand it is used to prevents from cacheing at proxy. I connect to the internet directly at home.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `max-stale=0`

```
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-stale=0"); // HTTP 1.1
```

Read more about it here [Modifications of the Basic Expiration Mechanism](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3)

Find complete list of [Cache-Control header fields](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

---

I have an **alternative solution** that works in all the cases. It's just a **trick** to make a new request for the resource.

Basically browser checks for the URL, if same URL is requested again then it first checks in cache and return it directly from cache if found.

#### Solution:

Just append a random unique number as query string in the URL of the request JSP page and it will **force the browser** to fetch the fresh copy of the JSP page because the URL has been changed.

For example you can append current time in milliseconds in the URL as query string.

Comment: I tried to change response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache") to response.setHeader("Cache-Control","max-stale=0"), still no luck. I only get updated jsp if I change my request parameter to a new value.

Comment: I haven't tried alternative solution but I can see it would work. However, I am trying to see if there are simple solution out there.I don't see many people having the same problem with jsp page when searched online.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your web.xml did not update the latest changes when you have made..Try the following steps :

"Clean and Build" whole project and then "Deploy".

Now run the project all over again..this may solve your problem